# React native navigation error : Route Login should declare a screen

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

I'm trying react navigation. I want to navigate from `login` screen to `Home` screen.When i declared `LoginScreen` within the StackNavigator i got the above error.Following is my code.

Updated:

**Route.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Profile from './Profile';
import CourseListing from './CourseListing';
import Faq from './Faq';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import CategoryDetail from './CategoryDetail';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import RegisterForm from './RegisterForm';
import DetailedView from './DetailedView';
import IndividualSection from './IndividualSection';

const StackScreens = StackNavigator({
    LoginForm:{screen: LoginForm},
    RegisterForm: {screen: RegisterForm},
    CourseListing:{screen: CourseListing},
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    CategoryDetail: {screen: CategoryDetail},
    DetailedView: {screen: DetailedView},
    IndividualSection: {screen: IndividualSection}
})

export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
   Home: {
     screen: StackScreens,
  },
  Profile: {
      screen: Profile
  },
  FAQ: {
      screen: Faq
  }
});
```

and i am importing this within `MyHome.js` as

```
import { MyDrawer} from 'LMS/src/components/Router';
class MyHome extends Component {


    render(){
        return(

        <MyDrawer />
        );
    }

}
export default MyHome;
```

also within `App.js` (main page)

```
return (

    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <MyHome />
    </View>

    );
```

Don't know what wrong i am doing.Please help.After clicking on Login button in `LoginForm`

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
render(){
return(

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}>
                                <Text style={{paddingLeft:50}}>Login</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
);
}
export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your route name is **Home** as you defined in your **Route.js**

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}>
```

and in your **Route.js** define **LoginForm** Screen also like below :-

```
    export const MyDrawer = DrawerNavigator({

     LoginForm: {
      screen :LoginForm
      },
      Home: {
         screen: StackScreens,
      },
      Profile: {
          screen: Profile
      },
      FAQ: {
          screen: Faq
      },
    });
```

Comment: I've tried the same but still getting this as error 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVPIb.png

Comment: check the above updated answer it will solve your error

Comment: you need to add  Route.js define LoginForm Screen also .

Comment: So i don't need to define` LoginForm` within `StackNavigator` right?

Comment: can you update what is your error where your app is crashing

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAph9.png this is what i'm getting. I think the problem is within `App.js` which is my route page.

Comment: yes you need to add LoginForm in Route.js , not in StackNavigator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164246/discussion-between-thunder-and-neethu-m).

Comment: are you there  ?

Answer (score 0):

The route name is Home not HomeScreen.

Just define the onPress as follows and it should work.

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}>
```

Also check your LoginForm import.
You might have import it like

```
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
```

but you might not have exported it default correctly.

The correct way to do it is:

```
export default class LoginForm
```

Comment: Can you please add the entire code in routes.js. Also the code of LoginForm

Comment: already export default class LoginForm is there in the end of his class code , check properly